# How can I make a focus ring More stiff?

Tags: lens, focus, fisheye, samyang

I have a manual focusing samyang fisheye lens with one problem.... The focus ring is feather touch and even the aperture ring getings knocked easily.

I want it to be less smooth so it's locked on to infinity and not constantly changing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

I use wide silicone rubber wrist bands and adjust it so that the edge overlays the adjusting ring to give the desired amount of resistance.

You can buy them marketed specifically for this use (i.e. LENSband, CreepStop), or just get generic wrist bands from any number of sources.

This is a generic band on my Nikon Z180-600, which has a surprising tendency for zoom creep.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

One simple solution is to use rubber band (these used for hair) and put one "end" under the lens hood, another "end" below the the focus ring. And with appropriate stretching you can "fix" the focus ring not to move easy.

Additionally friction between the rubber ring you add and the rubber ring of the focus ring will help minimizing the movement.